# Drive API v3 does not support css text-indent of submitted html

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

When we upload a html content having paragraphs with `text-indent`, they seems not being reflected in the document. Is it because text-indent are converted to span tags in the google doc? This only happen when negative value is there for test-indent.

We use below code to upload the html content

```
try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes())) {
            File fileMetaData = new File();
            fileMetaData.setMimeType(mimeType);
            InputStreamContent inputStreamContent = new InputStreamContent(DocumentMimeType.HTML.toString(), in);
            File updatedFile = drive.files()
                .update(fileId, fileMetaData, inputStreamContent)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
            Map<String, String> meta = new HashMap<>();
            return meta;
        }
```

Below is a html which has a citation format:

```
<html><body><p style="text-align: center;">Works Cited</p><p style="line-height:2em;text-indent:-24px;padding-left:24px;margin-top:2em;">"ACCENTURE & ORACLE DEPLOY CLOUD FOR WM POLICE." <i>Worldwide Databases</i>, vol. 30, no. 2, Jan. 2018, pp. 5-8. <i>ContentSelect Research Navigator</i>.</p><p style="line-height:2em;text-indent:-24px;padding-left:24px;margin-top:2em;">Flanagan, John Clemans, et al. <i>Science</i>. Westinghouse Learning Press, 1971.</p><p style="line-height:2em;text-indent:-24px;padding-left:24px;margin-top:2em;">Holton, Gerald. "Centennial Focus: Millikan's Measurement of Planck's Constant." <i>Focus</i>, vol. 3, 1999, doi:10.1103/physrevfocus.3.23.</p><p style="line-height:2em;text-indent:-24px;padding-left:24px;margin-top:2em;">"SCIFORMIX COLLABORATES WITH ORACLE HEALTH SCIENCES." <i>Worldwide Databases</i>, vol. 29, no. 12, 2017, pp. 3-7. <i>ContentSelect Research Navigator</i>.</p></body></html>
```